# having trouble connecting to my existing mysql database in flask app

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

```
engine = create_engine(engine_URL)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 387, in create_engine
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 56, in create
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 139, in _get_entrypoint
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 195, in load
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/dialects/__init__.py", line 30, in _auto_fn
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

my code

```
import os
import sys
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, REAL, DATE, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine_URL = URL('mysql://root:password@0.0.0.0:5000/dbase.sql')
engine = create_engine(engine_URL)
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.reflect(engine)

class User(Base):
    __table__ = Base.metadata.tables['user']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, Query
    db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
    for item in db_session.query(User.name):
        print item
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your connection URL string as the [**drivername**](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.params.drivername) to [`URL`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL). The resulting URL is

```
In [3]: engine_URL = URL('mysql://root:password@0.0.0.0:5000/dbase.sql')

In [4]: engine_URL
Out[4]: mysql://root:password@0.0.0.0:5000/dbase.sql://
```

If you want to use an instance of `URL`, and create it from a connection string, use [`make_url`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.url.make_url):

```
In [8]: engine_URL = make_url('mysql://root:password@0.0.0.0:5000/dbase.sql')

In [9]: engine_URL
Out[9]: mysql://root:***@0.0.0.0:5000/dbase.sql
```

You could also just pass the connection URL string as is to [`create_engine()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine).